# can we use datetime filter in MATCH clause instead of WHERE clause on a node

Tags: neo4j

I have some sample tweets stored as neo4j. Below query finds top hashtags from specific country. It is taking a lot of time because the time filter for status type nodes is in where clause and is slowing the response. Is it possible to move this filter to MATCH clause so that status nodes are filtered before relationships are found?

```
match (c:country{countryCode:"PK"})-[*0..4]->(s:status)-[*0..1]->(h:hashtag) where (s.createdAt >= datetime('2017-06-01T00:00:00') AND s.createdAt
>= datetime('2017-06-01T23:59:59')) return h.name,count(h.name) as hCount order by hCount desc limit 100
```

thanks

Comment: no, at least you have the exact datetime value to compare the nodes like if you using an equals. Like in your query "(c:country{countryCode:"PK"})", but you cant do something like: (c:country{id>=1})

Comment: In addition, whether the predicate is in the match or the where clause shouldn't matter, that's syntactical sugar, the planner interprets them the same way.

Comment: You may also want to double-check your `createdAt` comparison, as you seem to be looking for a time that is greater than or equal to both values, as opposed to between them.

Comment: that's just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, whether a predicate for a property is in the MATCH clause or the WHERE clause shouldn't matter, as this is just syntactical sugar and is interpreted the same way by the query planner.

You can use PROFILE or EXPLAIN to see the query plan to see what it's doing. PROFILE will give you more information but will have to actually execute the query. You can attempt to use [planner hints](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/using/) to force the planner to plan the match differently which may yield a better approach.

You will want to ensure you have an index on :status(createdAt).

You can also try altering your match a little, and moving the portion connecting to the country in question into your WHERE clause instead. Also it's a good idea to get the count based upon the hashtag node itself (assuming there's only one :hashtag node for a given name) so you can order and limit before you do property access:

```
MATCH (s:status)-[*0..1]->(h:hashtag) 
WHERE (s.createdAt >= datetime('2017-06-01T00:00:00') AND s.createdAt
>= datetime('2017-06-01T23:59:59'))
AND (:country{countryCode:"PK"})-[*0..4]->(s)
WITH h, count(h) as hCount
ORDER BY hCount DESC
LIMIT 100
RETURN h.name, hCount
```